# Mostrar edit de un registro existente de una tabla en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una base de datos a la que le estoy creando una interfaz web con php y html, algo simple.

En un php, visualizo un listado de todos los usuarios de la base de datos, a los que les he añadido botones de edit y delete.

El edit enlaza a otro php, en el que se muestra un formulario para rellenar. Lo que no consigo hacer es que en los valores del formulario aparezcan los datos previos que tiene el usuario en la tabla.

Gracias de antemano.

```
<?php

    $OK = true; 
    $usuario="root";
    $contrasena="";
    $urlConexion='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webdesigner';
    try{
        $conexion=new PDO($urlConexion, $usuario, $contrasena);
        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if (isset($_GET['id_user'])) {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_user = ?';
            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            $result = $stmt->execute(array($_GET['id_user']));
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            if (empty($row)) {
                $result = "No se encontraron resultados.";
            }
        }
        if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)) {
            $sql = 'UPDATE users SET username = ?, password = ?, email = ?, usertype = ?, company = ?, phone = ? WHERE id_user = ?';
            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            $OK = $stmt->execute(array($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['usertype'],$_POST['company'],$_POST['phone'],$_GET['id_user']));
            $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
        if (!$OK) {
            echo $error[2];
        } else {
            echo 'El registro se ha actualizado correctamente.';

        }
    }

        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo ($e-GetMessage());
            die("<h3>Se ha producido una excepción</h3>");
        }

?>

<?php
        if(!$OK) :
            echo "";
        else :
?>


        <fieldset>
            <legend>Editar datos del usuario</legend>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <br/>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="id_user">ID:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="id_user" id="id_user" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $row['id_user'];?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="username">Username:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $row['username'];?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $row['password'];?>"></td>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="company">Company:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $row['company'];?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="phone">Phone:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $row['phone'];?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="usertype">Usertype:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="usertype" id="usertype" value="<?php echo $row['usertype'];?>"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                <br/>   
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Actualizar"/>
            </form>
        </fieldset>



    <?php endif;?>


    <input type="button" value="Volver" onClick="location.href='listarusuarios.php'"/>
</body>
```

Comment: se esta enviando correctamente el parametro id_user por la URL, `pagina.php?id_user=12`?

Comment: Te pregunto, por que en el caso, de que no venga esa variable, osea no se compruebe que el `isset` da `true`, y no ingresa en el siguiente `IF`, la aplicación no dará ningún error o excepcion, mostrandote el formulario sin datos.

Comment: Sí, el enlace recoge correctamente la id que se va a editar y se la pasa al php

Comment: Bueno, en el caso de que `$row` sea vacío, le das un valor a `$result` con un mensaje. Si eso pasa. El resultado es que mostrará tu formulario sin datos, pues en ningón momento muestras la variable `$result`

Answer (score 2):

El resultado de tu consulta es un array con todas las filas que calzan. Aunque sea sólo una fila, es un array. Significa que en vez de usar $row, tienes que usar $row[0].